# Is there any way to convert pyspark random forest model to pmml？

Tags: pyspark

I have trained RandomForest in pyspark2.1, but saved as pyspark model file.

```
rf_model = RandomForestClassifier(featuresCol='features',
                              labelCol='click',
                              maxDepth=10,
                              maxBins=32,
                              numTrees=100,
                             )
model = rf_model.fit(dftrain)
model_path = 'hdfs://hacluster/user/model'
model.save(model_path)
```

But now,we have downloaded the model without the dftrain data and cannot access to the hdfs right now. Is there any way to convert model file to pmml without exact train data?

I already knew pyspark2pmml or jpmml-sparkml, both have train data as input.Like,

```
from jpmml_sparkml import toPMMLBytes
pmmlBytes = toPMMLBytes(sc, dftrain, pipelineModel)
print(pmmlBytes)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I already knew pyspark2pmml or jpmml-sparkml, both have train data as input.

The [JPMML-SparkML](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-sparkml) library (either directly or via the [PySpark2PMML](https://github.com/jpmml/pyspark2pmml) wrapper library) is still your only option. However, you should check out its README file to refresh your knowledge about it - your example uses outdated API (`toPMMLBytes` utility method instead of `PMMLBuilder#buildByteArray` builder method).

Regarding the need for the training dataset, then JPMML-SparkML needs to know the **schema** (in the form of `org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType` object) of the training dataset, **not the actual data**. This schema is used for getting column names, data types, and other metadata.

If you don't have the original schema available, then it shouldn't be difficult to create one programmatically.